# Unable to copy files to pendrive

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, usb-drive

I've a dualboot mode for Ubuntu and Windows. Earlier, everything was working perfectly fine. But, I'm unable to copy any files to pendrive.

I know this question has been asked several times, but my issue is different. The file copies to pendrive, but once I unplug and re-plug my pd, the file is no longer there. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Does it happen also in Windows or only Ubuntu?

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem, that the pendrive is damaged beyond repair. But it is possible, that there is 'only' confusion and you can find a solution. You can analyze the problems according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia only Ubuntu. It works perfectly on Windows

Comment: @sudodus My pendrive isn't damaged. Its working fine in my friend's pc as well as on windows in mine...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the symptoms; 1. After copying, run the command `sync` from a terminal window. When it returns to prompt, the write process has finished, the data should reside on the pendrive, *if it is healthy*. It is important to **unmount** (or eject) the partition on the drive before it is unplugged (unmount includes syncing); 2. There might also be a problem with mounting, that the partition on the drive is read-only (but the file should not 'copy' in that case. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

Comment: @sudodus Thank you soo much!!! I always "safely remove" the pendrive, but the `sync` command was actually helpful. Whatever the process, I finally got the results! Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you find a solution :-)